# Recommend good books for a beginner to learn about Support Vector Machines (SVM)

Tags: book-recommendation

I am doing a semester project on Support Vector Machines, where I am supposed to read up on the mathematics behind it, as well as give some proofs of the mathematics.

I am an undergraduate, with a foundation of linear algebra and optimization.

However, I cannot find any textbooks that teaches support vector machines in details...

Can I get some recommendations?

Video recommendations are welcome too, but ultimately, I need a strong working foundation of SVMs enough for me to write a 25 page report.

Comment: Just for curiosity: what is Support Vector Machines?

Comment: A topic of machine learning

Comment: At the risk of being contrarian, SVM's are going out of style these days.

Comment: Just because they're going out of style doesn't mean they still aren't useful in some situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a background in optimization, I recommend reading the explanation of Support Vector Machines that appears in Chapter 8 of Boyd and Vandenberghe ([free online](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)).

The book [Linear and Nonlinear Optimization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898716616), by Griva, has several pages about Support Vector Machines.

I've also heard good things about the book [Learning with Kernels: Support Vector Machines, Regularization, Optimization, and Beyond](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262194759), by Scholkopf and Smola.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that [Christopher Bishop's](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pattern-Recognition-Learning-Information-Statistics/dp/0387310738) book on pattern recognition and machine learning has been a very nice text. Andrew Ng also has some great video lectures on machine learning and SVMs if you have a Google.

Answer (score 2):

There is a book named $\textbf{An Introduction to Support Vector Machines and Other Kernel-based Learning Methods}$ and is dedicated entirely to SVM covering both theoretical as well as numerical aspects of SVM.

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Support-Machines-Kernel-based-Learning/dp/0521780195](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521780195)

Answer (score 1):

Can't believe no one mentioned Alexandre Kowalczyk's book, which is free: https://www.svm-tutorial.com/2017/10/support-vector-machines-succinctly-released/ (that site has many blog posts, the book can be found here, now: https://www.syncfusion.com/succinctly-free-ebooks/support-vector-machines-succinctly)

I've found it to explain the math well.